# How do I avoid 'bottom-aligned' labels with inline associated inputs?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I use a 'ul' tag for form fields and in each of its `li` tags I place a label and input, using  the standard Html.Label and Html.Editor helpers, except for dropdowns, where I use the DevExpress `ComboBox` extension. This renders a table instead of a select tag, which is fine, but when I set the CSS *display* attribute on this table to 'inline-block' to place it next to it's label, the label gets pushed down, where it would normally middle align with the input, it now 'bottom-aligns' with the input. How can I align the 'Course Type' label the same as the 'Name' label in the image? [image]

The rendered HTML is very like the following, just shortened for brevity:

```
<li>
    <label for="" style="width: 80px;">*Course Type</label>
    <table class="dxeButtonEdit_Office2010Black">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
```

Comment: can you clean the table?

Comment: Could you expand the code example to show two or three of the content-rows? And, ideally, post the relevant CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "**inline-table**" style instead:

[Possible ways of arranging DevExpress controls within a page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18357.aspx)

[Data Editors - Model Validation](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/Editors/ModelValidation)

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, I just copied the CSS from the second link and it's working.